# How to reactively check for changes from a window opened by my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have a Meteor app component that opens a new window - some activity happens in the new window, which then needs to prompt the original component to close the window and continue. I am able to write to localStorage in the new window, and read that localStorage in the original component - but I can't find a way to reactively watch for the change in the original component, how do I do this?

Comment: You're trying to signal one window from the other? If you write to local storage then you're going to have to poll to see the change. OR you could write to a collection that both windows are subscribed to and then react to the change from there. You unfortunately can't share reactive variables across the two windows since each is running it's own independent copy of the app. Another approach would be to use a modal and keep everything in the original window.

Comment: Thanks, I actually managed to find a library that makes localStorage reactive... see answer below

Comment: Oh, very nice! Didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 0):

I found a library that creates a reactive version of localStorage that can be watched with a Tracker.autorun - https://github.com/simplyGits/reactive-local-storage